# Matrix equation $X + X^T = \operatorname{Tr}(X)A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Solve $X+X^T= (\operatorname{Tr}(X))A $ where the unknown $X$ is in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

$X^T$ is the transpose of $X$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(X)$ is the trace of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a solution, we obtain by taking the trace of the two sides of the equation $2Tr(X)=Tr(X)Tr(A)$

$\bullet$ If $Tr(X)=0$, then $X^T=-X$: $X$ is antisymmetric. Reciprocally, every antisymmetric matrix is a solution of the equation.

$\bullet$ If $Tr(X)\neq 0$, then $Tr(A)=2$ and $A=\frac{1}{Tr(X)}(X+X^T)$ is symmetric. We therefore have:

$$(X-\frac{Tr(X)}{2}A)+(X-\frac{Tr(X)}{2}A)^T=0$$

and so $X=\frac{Tr(X)}{2}A$ is antisymmetric. In other words, there exists $B$ antisymmetric such that $$X=\frac{Tr(X)}{2}A+B$$
Reciprocally, if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ et B is antisymmetric, $X= \lambda A+B$ is the solution. In fact, we have $Tr(X)= \lambda Tr(A)=2 \lambda$ and $X+X^T=2\lambda A= (TR(X))A$

CONCLUSION: If $Tr(A)\neq 2$ or if $A$ is not symmetric, the only solutions are the antisymmetric matrices. If $Tr(A)=2$ and $A$ is symmetric, the solutions are of the form $\lambda A+B$ such that $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is antisymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding the condition $\rm{Tr} X=0$, we get $X^T=-X$, i.e. $X$ is antisymmetric. Conversely, any antisymmetric matrix has zero diagonal, hence $0$ trace. So the solution set contains the **antisymmetric matrices $\mathcal AS_n(\mathbb{R})$**.
2. With the extra condition $\rm{Tr} X\neq 0$, the equation is equivalent to
   $$A=\frac{1}{\rm{Tr} X} (X+X^T).$$ 
   So $A$ must be symmetric with $\rm{Tr} A=2\rm{Tr} X/\rm{Tr} X=2$ for solutions to exist. Then $X_0=A$ is a particular solution. Also note that $X$ is a solution if and only if $tX$ is a solution for every $t\neq 0$. So assume $\rm{Tr} X=2$. Then $X$ is solution if and only if $Y=X-A$ is solution of $Y+Y^T=0$, that is $Y$ is antisymmetric. This yields the solutions $A+\mathcal AS_n(\mathbb{R})$ multiplied by any nonzero constant, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^*A+\mathcal AS_n(\mathbb{R})$.

These two sets together yield the solution set
$$
\mathbb{R}A+\mathcal AS_n(\mathbb{R})
$$
when $A$ is symmetric and $\rm{Tr} A=2$.

Or simply 
$$
\mathcal AS_n(\mathbb{R})
$$
when $A$ does not fulfill the above conditions.

Comment: I didn't see yours until now

Comment: @user43418 I'm glad to see there is no problem. Take care.

Comment: I'm sorry but Carpediem's answer is more clear for me

Comment: @user43418 No problem. That's your question. You do whatever you want. You apparently don't like my "style" given what happened today. I'll live with it.

Answer (score 0):

since $\operatorname{Tr}(X^{\top})=\operatorname{Tr}(X)$, first solve
$$
2Y=\operatorname{Tr}(Y)A
$$
then find $X$ such that
$$
X+X^{\top}=2Y
$$
note that, if $\operatorname{Tr}(Y)\neq0$, then $Y$ (and thus $A$) has to be symmetric or else there are no solutions